# Is it possible to change slotted instance method dynamically?

Tags: python

Failing example(`_call` is read-only):

```py
class SingletonFactory:
    __slots__ = ('singleton_instance', )

    def __init__(self):
        self.singleton_instance = None

    def __call__(self):
        return self._call()

    def _call(self):
        
        # logic to instantiate singleton_instance


        # as we init only once it is possible to avoid if-else by
        # overwriting method
        self._call = self._return_instance

        return self.singleton_instance

    def _return_instance(self):
        return self.singleton_instance
```

Obviously if I remove `__slots__` it will work. But is there any way to make it work with `__slots__`?

Comment: `__slots__` is for reducing the memory footprint over many small instances.  It makes zero sense to use for a singleton, which by definition has a single instance.

Comment: @wim well, the other use-case, I believe the original one, was to make attribute access quicker (doesn't require a hash lookup).

Comment: Use `type(self)._call = type(self)._return_instance`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga right about access. Your answer overrides class level, not instance level

Comment: @wim IRL it factory that takes any class and ensure returning only same singel instance of it on call, so there may many instances of factory for different classes.